# Regularity of an ODE: series Ansatz, analytic and numerical solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Suppose I have an ODE that can be written as $$ E(y'(x),y(x),x)=0 $$
Suppose also that this equation has a closed-form solution for $y(x)$, that is
$$y(x) =y(x,C)$$
for an integration constant $C$.
If I know from "physical arguments" that this function ought to be even (say because it is defined on a 3-sphere where x is the third hyper-spherical coordinate), I might get the idea of substituting in a sort of power series ansatz
$$ y(x)= \sum_{i=-1}^{m} y_i x^i$$
where $m$ is some truncation number. This yield an identically vanishing polynomial, from the coefficients of which I might verify that indeed, only the even components of $y_i$ are non-zero.

My first problem is, and this already tells me that the integration constant $C$ in the analytic solution has to take a specific value (zero in my case), if its series expansion around $x=0$  coincides with the $y_i$ coefficients calculated from the polynomial. Is this because a regularity (even power-series) at $x=0$ acts a sort of boundary condition, hence determining the integration constant?

My second problem is, that even though on paper this function should be regular at the $x=0$ origin, in numerical solutions there IS a singularity there. How can this be, if $y_{-1}=0$ ? Should the numeric solution not go as$$ y_\text{numeric} \propto y_{0}+y_{2} x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^4)   \;\;\;?$$

Comment: You start pretty general, but your later steps only make sense if the equation is a (singular) linear DE. Could you give a non-trivial concrete example, especially for your numerical integration attempt?

Comment: And it is "Ansatz" (like in making some preparation or base), related to the "sitzen/setzen" (approx. sit and set) verbs.

Comment: Why does the equation need to be linear? It isn't in my case..

Comment: This was just an impression, as power series solutions mostly work with linear DE. The same about the discussion of regular singularity.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't very clear! That (finite) series is rather just a "taylor expansion" (with a $y_{-1} x^{-1}$ term) locally around x=0 to gauge the regularity of $y(x)$, it wasn't meant to be a global solution.

Comment: Is only accounting for $x^{-1}$ dictated in your problem? Because if the numerics suggest a singularity, but my first guess is not detecting it, then I'd either try to account for it with more negative powers and see if they give something, or maybe the singularity is too mild to be seen by powers of $x$ (a logarithmic divergence for example).